# How to create a dummy only if a column has non-zero values for certain dates but zero for other dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say, I want to identify traders who only traded during bull runs but did not trade (zero values) during downturns or stable periods. Let's say we have two bull runs, `2018Q4`, `2021Q4`. Below, `D` starts trading only from `2021Q4` (the second bull run period) but I want to include this as =1 well.

This is my df.

```
id  date    value  other variables..  
A   2019Q4     2 
A   2020Q4     2   
A   2021Q4     3
B   2018Q4     2
B   2019Q4     0
B   2020Q4     0
B   2021Q4     4
C   2020Q4     3
C   2021Q4     4
D   2021Q4     4
E   2018Q4     3
E   2019Q4     0
E   2020Q4     0
E   2021Q4     2
.       .
```

desired output would be

```
id  dummy
A     0
B     1
C     0
D     1
E     1
.       .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test if both values not equal `0` and test both quarters, compare (thanks mozway for improvement) and last aggregate [`GroupBy.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.all.html) for test if all `True`s per groups:

```
m1 = df['value'].ne(0)
m2 = df['date'].isin(['2018Q4','2021Q4'])

df1 = (m1 == m2).groupby(df['id']).all().astype(int).reset_index(name='dummy')
print (df1)
  id  dummy
0  A      0
1  B      1
2  C      0
3  D      1
4  E      1
```

Comment: you should rather use `(m1==m2).groupby(...)` for efficiency